# efficient way to administer or manage an auto-scaling instances in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, admin, autoscaling

As a sysadmin, i'm looking for an efficient way or best practices that you do on managing an ec2 instances with autoscaling.

How you manage automate this following scenario: (our environment is running with autoscaling, Elastic Load Balancing and cloudwatch)

1. patching the latest version of the rpm packages of the server for security reasons? like (yup update/upgrade)
2. making a configuration change of the Apache server like a change of the httpd.conf and apply it to all instances in the auto-scaling group?
3. how do you deploy the latest codes to your app to the server with less disruption in production?
4. how do you use puppet or chef to automate your admin task?

I would really appreciate if you have anything to share on how you automate your administration task with aws

Comment: How did you go with this. Any of the answers the ones you were after?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Amazon [OpsWorks](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/), the new Chef based DevOps tool for Amazon Web Services.

It gives you the ability to run custom Chef recipes on your instances in the different layers (Load Balancer, App servers, DB...), as well as to manage the deployment of your app from various source repositories (Git, Subversion..).

It supports auto-scaling based on load (like the auto-scaling that you are already using), as well as auto-scaling based on time, which is more complex to achieve with standard EC2 auto-scaling.

This is relatively a young service and not all functionality is available already, but it might be useful for your.

Comment: hi guy, any other way how to do my scenarios without using opsworks?

Comment: You can use the standard EC2 auto-scaling. You can create new launch configuration which the new version, that will start launching your new version until it replace the old configuration. The new version can be defined by new AMI, different User-Data or Puppet/Chef configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> patching the latest version of the rpm packages of the server for
>   security reasons? like (yup update/upgrade)

You can use puppet or chef to create a cron job that takes care of this for you (the cron would in its most basic form download and or install updates via a bash script). You may want to automatically upgrade, or simply notify an admin via email so you can evaluate before apply updates.

> making a configuration change of the Apache server like a change of
>   the httpd.conf and apply it to all instances in the auto-scaling
>   group?

I usually handle all of my configuration files through my Puppet manifest. You could setup each EC2 instance to pull updates from a Puppet Server, then you can roll out changes on demand. Part of this process should be updating the AMI stored in your AutoScale group (this is done with the Amazon Command Line tools).

> how do you deploy the latest codes to your app to the server with less
>   disruption in production?

Test it in staging first! Also a neat trick is to versioned deployments, so each time you do a deployment it gets its own folder (/var/www/v1 /var/www/v2 etc) and once you have verified the deployment was successful you simply update a symlink to point to the lastest version (/var/www/current points to /var/www/v2).

OpsWorks handles all this sort of stuff for you so you can look into that if you don't want to do it all yourself.

> how do you use puppet or chef to automate your admin task?

You can use Chef or Puppet to do all sorts of things, and anything they can't (or you don't know how to) do can be done via a bash/python script that you invoke from Chef or Puppet.

I normally do things like install packages, build custom packages, set permissions, download things, start services, manage configuration files, setup cron jobs etc

> I would really appreciate if you have anything to share on how you automate your administration task with aws

Look into CloudFormation. This can help you setup all your servers and related services (think EC2, LBS, CloudWatch) through configuration files, thus helping you to automate your entire stack (not just the EC2's Operating System).

Comment: Drew, have a quick question about auto-scaling and puppet.I have my infrastructure managed by puppet. I update the latest release tarball in S3, then have a simple script to pull and replace the latest release during boot (rc.local). I would also like the auto-scaled instances to register with puppetmaster, but not sure how to handle the hostnames and cert signing. Thought about checking existing hostnames and incrementing the hostname, then registering with puppetmaster, but is there a correct/better way of doing this? I use autosign in master and allow by *.domain.com. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a new question not a comment on this answer?